# HTML / CSS: Mostrar texto en Tag Select

Tags: html, css

En este momento estoy trabajando con un estilo css que me permite darle una forma circular  a los `inputs`, pero no me funciona bien con los `selects`, los items no se muestran cuando los selecciono y además me gustaría que la lista desplegable se muestre circular al igual que el select.

```html
<style>
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #6e707e;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #d1d3e2;
    border-radius: 0.35rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.form-control-user {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 10rem;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
}


</style>



<input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password" style="width: 250px; height:;">
<br>
<select class="form-control form-control-user" style="width: 250px;">
  <option selected>Select</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[image: El area desplegada enmarcada en rojo me gustaría que se mostrara acorde al select.]

Nota: No deseo involucrar JavaScript, y deseo conservar el estilo, al menos para mostrar el texto seleccionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empieza por quitar la sigiente linea al css del select:

```
padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
```

Con esto ya verás el contenido de los option, con el resto, no creo que se pueda hacer con css, seguramente lo encuentras con javascript pero no lo veo muy estético.

Si tu problema es con el tamaño, puedes quitar la linea:

```
height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
```

Y dejar que el padding controle el alto de los inputs.

Comment: Está casi perfecto, el problema es que mira como se muestra https://i.imgur.com/IOq6JQA.png

Comment: Lo que pasa es que le estas dando diferentes paddings y tienen un height, quítale ese height y dales el mismo padding a ambos

Comment: Listo, gracias, problema resuelto. Lo del select si veré entonces como lo resuelvo con javascript